# Create new column when text runs over div height in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a multicolumn layout in html that will run from left to right instead of vertical. I want to set the text column div to a certain height and width, and when/if the text overflows the box, it will create a new column for the text. So an auto column creator that adds when more is needed. Is this possible?

Comment: Check this [demo](http://randysimons.com/overige/multicolumn/) here.

Comment: This is cool, but it appears to make the columns fit the width of the window. I want something that will continue to extend horizontally.

Comment: Modify the script as you need. If you encounter any problem, post another question here.

Comment: I don't even know where to start with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could answer for Gecko 10, that by using `-moz-column-count: 1` and setting the the height, the overflow content appears to the right instead.

I wasn't able to control the width using `-moz-column-width` with column count set to 1. I had to specify the `width` there (or else the container follows parent width).

But if I set `-moz-column-count: auto`, I can instead set `-moz-column-width` without setting `width`.

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syockit/mVFaX/1/

Comment: this is helpful. I seem to have an issue where the column gaps resize with the window though. I can't seem to make it be a solid layout vs fluid. What am I missing?

Comment: this actually seemed like the way to go, but then I found all sorts of overflow issues, so now I need to figure out how do deal with that

Comment: it doesn't allow you to have any padding or margin on the right side.

Comment: using jquery and span to get the width of the text and then setting the width of the div works.